# Broken Eclipse syntax highlight behavior for PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

The initial syntax highlight when opening files looks fine, but after editing a few lines, syntax highlighter fails:

[image: Eclipse PDT Syntax Highlight #FAIL]

FYI I'm also using [Eclipse Theme Plugin](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/). Any idea?

---

Update (Feb 20, 2011): Here is the unloved [bug issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320181).

Update (Jul 1, 2015): **The issue has been marked as resolved today after about 4 years! The resolver says that it was because of model synchronization.**

Comment: Sounds like you should be making a bug report... and for what it's worth I used to get this issue with Aptana, but only when I opened the same file in more than one tab.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Oh, If Gedit had a built-in debugger!

Comment: @Sepehr Lajevardi: I don't think I've ever encountered a syntax highlighter for PHP that worked perfectly (other than using the PHP engine to parse it properly).

Comment: @Sepehr Lajevardi: Most have trouble switching between PHP and HTML, some have hassles with strings, especially when you use quotes inside strings, or interpolation.  Heredoc isn't ideal either.  PHP is quite hard to parse it seems.

Comment: Orbling, I had pretty good experiences with ZendStudio, Vim, Gedit, etc. syntax highlighters. This time it's just a Eclipse bug (hopefully). I just findout the issue at eclipse PDT queue. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320181